# How to prevent text in TD from overlapping with small logo in corner

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is displaying the top 4 finishers each year of a certain tournament. Each td includes the `team`, `team_location`, as well as a small image of a medal (gold, silver, and bronze) to indicate the placement of the team.

I'm aligning the medal using `float: right` in css, but I'm running into issues where some team names overlap with the logo. How can I ensure that the logo won't be overlapped by the other text in `td`? Here is a stackblitz with a bit of an example, although I can't get images to work on stackblitz, so I've attached a screenshot with an example of the issue I'm having:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yysxgw?file=src/app/app.component.css

[image]

One other issue--how can I prevent the logo from off-centering the text as seen in the `Team Canada` td?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a padding to the right of the `td` tag to stop the text from reaching the `img` tag.
And set a negative margin to move the `img` into that padded area.

Or you could leave an extra padding on the right and set the `img` tag to `position: absolute` and place it inside that padded area.

```css
.medal {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 -25px 0 0;
}

img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table td {
  padding-right: 35px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="champ_header">Year</th>
      <th class="champ_header">Champion</th>
      <th class="champ_header">Runner Up</th>
      <th class="champ_header">Semi-Finalist</th>
      <th class="champ_header">Semi-Finalist</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>2019</td>
    <td><span><img src="https://www.vippng.com/png/full/540-5402602_medal-png-image-background-gold-medal-icon-png.png" class="medal"></span>United States</td>
    <td><span><img src="https://www.vippng.com/png/full/540-5402602_medal-png-image-background-gold-medal-icon-png.png" class="medal"></span>Canadaadadadadaadadadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadad</td>
    <td><span><img src="https://www.vippng.com/png/full/540-5402602_medal-png-image-background-gold-medal-icon-png.png" class="medal"></span>Italy</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```